# flink - zeppelin - not responding

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zeppelin

I am unable to run flink (1.0.3) process in zepplin. It is pending and web ui is not recording the process: both in cluster and local mode. Flink itself works fine in command line and intellij. I built zeppelin as `mvn clean package`. 
Has anyone had a similar issue?  Do I need to amend zeppelin-env.sh to rectify filk? I am unable to kill process in zeppelin web ui had to use `./bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh restart`
[image: penindig status]

[image]

Comment: What did your Zeppelin-Flink logs say? 
`zeppelin_dir/logs/*flink*log`

Hey, I've done some work with Flink+Zeppelin. When this sort of thing happens, the most likely cause in my experience is Zeppelin is running the background which has left an orphaned version of Flink running. Especially since Flink-Zeppelin isn't even working in localmode.  Makes me think it can't bind to that port.

If you're running Zeppelin on a *nix box, try something like
`ps aux | grep zeppelin`

Answer (score 3):

I am using Flink 1.2 but I had the same problem.

I did two thing and it worked for me.

First of all, update your version. After, in the Interpreter I changed the value **host** = local to your localhost IP address.

Second, kill all the procces of Flink in terminal, just use web ui of Zeppelin.

You can check everything is going fine writting:

```
%flink
senv
res0: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment = org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment@48388d9f
```

Let me know how it is going.
Regards! :)